# Problem in installing the clubhouse via APT command

Tags: apt, software-installation

I am trying to install the clubhouse directly from the apt command and I get the below error:

```
sudo apt install clubhouse
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done

No apt package "clubhouse", but there is a snap with that name.
Try "snap install clubhouse"

E: Unable to locate package clubhouse
```

The reason for this try is I can not run the snap clubhouse, as you can see below:

[image]

And I guess the problem of my snap version of it is because of the government or ISP filtering the clubhouse. But for becoming sure I need to install the clubhouse by `apt` command and I asked here.

**Update:**

I have tried the **N0rbert** suggested codes via the answer, and now I received the SMS from my active clubhouse on my phone (currently work on my android phone). But when I paste the code on the above Ubuntu app it doesn't respond, and stuck on this verification step as you can see below:

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: If Clubhouse does not provide a .deb installer, then you're restricted to the Snap version, and there's not much we can do.  Not everything is packaged in Debian packages.

Comment: In the Snap is not working, then please file a bug report with the Snap author.

Answer (score 1):

Clubhouse [does not have](https://repology.org/project/clubhouse-desktop/versions) deb-packaged version. Snap is not working for you.

So there is alternative method - transform [ArchLinux PKGBUILD](https://aur.archlinux.org/cgit/aur.git/tree/PKGBUILD?h=clubhouse-desktop-bin) to plain Ubuntu install commands as shown below:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget -c https://github.com/callmearta/clubhouse-desktop/releases/download/1.0.2/clubhouse-linux-x64.zip
sudo unzip clubhouse-linux-x64.zip -d /opt
sudo wget -c "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c3/Clubhouse_App_Logo.svg?download" -O /opt/clubhouse-linux-x64/clubhouse.svg
sudo ln -s /opt/clubhouse-linux-x64/clubhouse /usr/local/bin/clubhouse

sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/share/applications
cat << EOF | sudo tee /usr/local/share/applications/clubhouse.desktop
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Clubhouse Desktop
Icon=/opt/clubhouse-linux-x64/clubhouse.svg
Exec=clubhouse
Terminal=false
Type=Application
StartupWMClass=Clubhouse
Comment=An unofficial Clubhouse desktop client
Categories=Utility;
EOF

update-menus
```

and then run it as `clubhouse` or using menu

Comment: Thanks, @N0rbert, I have tried your suggested codes, and  now I received the SMS from my active clubhouse on my phone (currently work on my android phone).  But when I  paste the code on the above Ubuntu app it doesn't respond, and stuck on this verification step as you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Kmrv.png)